# Extracting values to new columns with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where the coordinates column comes in this format

```
[-7.821, 37.033]
```

I would like to create two columns where the first is `lon`and the second is `lat`

I've tried

```
my_dict = df_map['coordinates'].to_dict()
df_map_new = pd.DataFrame(list(my_dict.items()),columns = ['lon','lat'])
```

But the dictionary that is created does not split the values between `,`
Instead it creates a dict with the following format

```
0: '[-7.821, 37.033]'
```

What is the best way to extract the values within [,] and put them into two new columns in the original dataframe `df_map`?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert values to lists by `ast.literal_eval`, then to lists instead dicts:

```
import ast

my_L = df_map['coordinates'].apply(ast.literal_eval).tolist()
df_map_new = pd.DataFrame(my_L,columns = ['lon','lat'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can parse string:

```
pattern = r"\[(?P<lon>.*),\s*(?P<lat>.*)\]"
out = df_map['coordinates'].str.extract(pattern).astype(float)
print(out)

# Output
     lon     lat
0 -7.821  37.033
```

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to the answers already provided, you can also try this:

```
ser_lon = df['coordinates'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
ser_lat = df['coordinates'].apply(lambda x: x[1])

df_map['lon'] = ser_lon
df_map['lat'] = ser_lat
```